# Field Dependency-How can i use 1 controlling field to 2 dependents

Tags: record-type, field-dependencies

I have a Sub type controlling field and the Category__c is it's dependent.
The Category__c field is also a controlling field.
And it has 2 dependents: Transaction__c and Transaction_SRU__c.

I want to disable the Transaction__c field when a certain value from Sub type is selected.
Is there any connections with the field dependency with the ones i want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly disable Transaction__c field based on Sub type field.  You need to include Category__c field since this is a controlling field of Transaction__c.  If you want to disable then create new field dependency between Sub type and Transaction__c fields.

Below is the Idea link kindly vote for this feature.

[Multi level field dependencies](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br1a)

Comment: Thank you for this.